# iOS app crashing immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS app is crashing immediately without any debug info. I have a break point all objective-c exceptions.

Crashing on this line

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([STAppDelegate class]));
```

App was running fine for the past month and nothing was changed.

1. I cleaned are re-ran.

What is weird is it is crashing every other time I run so run once its good stop it and run again crashed .... repeat rinse same result... every other time.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855627/app-crashes-while-loading-with-error-in-main-m

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using? I bet the 4.6.2. If so update to the latest 4.6.3 which fixes an issue relevant to the ldb

Comment: Check default.png mainwindow.xib or main storyboard

Comment: This -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113848/ios-app-crashing-every-other-launch-cant-find-error?rq=1

Comment: I am getting closer after installing 4.6.2.  Now it crashes everytime and I get this error."erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting closer after installing 4.6.2. Now it crashes everytime and I get this error."erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate'"

This is an altogether different story, it looks like a problem similar to use *autolayout* on iOS version lower than 6.x...
**You cannot use storyboard with iOS 5.x as deployment target**.

Getting back to your original problem, [Xcode 4.6.2 app crashes on every second run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113036/xcode-4-6-2-app-crashes-on-every-second-run), it gets solved either updating to the latest XCode 4.6.3 or using GDB instead of LLDB. I suggest, however, to update to the latest version and hence use LLDB - by the way, it looks like the next XCode 5 will support exclusively LLDB.